# String length prints weird numbers. Where is the issue in my code?

Tags: c, string, loops, execution

My task is: Write a program that calculates the length of a string without using the  library

This is my answer, but there is a problem with execution. The length doesnt show properly ! the execution shows length as 107 or 127 for any string I insert.

````
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
   //Declaration of variables :
   char ch[50+1];
   int length, i;

   //data :
   printf("ch : ");
   scanf("%s", &ch);
   printf("\n");

   //Search length of string :
   i = 0;
   do
   {
       if(ch[i] == '\0')
       {
           length = i;
       }
       else
       {
           i++;
       }
   }
   while(ch[i] != '\0');

   //Result "
   printf("length pf %s is : %d \n", ch, length);

   return 0;
} ```
````

Comment: Step through your program. The line `length = i;` never gets executed. (I think the compiler should have warned you about this, so check your compiler flags.)

Comment: no it didn't. the program executes but shows a length of 107

Comment: "*for any string i insert !*" - Note that you can only insert a string up to 50 characters. Else you write beyond the bounds of the array which invokes undefined behavior. Use a length modifier to ensure that this won´t happen like `scanf("%50s", ch);`

Comment: That is not true. It shows an *uninitialized* value; you yourself say that it *sometimes* returns one or another. Don't believe me? Test it by adding `length = 2020;` **before** the loop. Now it will always return `2020`.

Comment: okay then why didnt the do while loop get the length ? where is the bug please ?

Comment: BTW: `scanf("%s", &ch);` -> `scanf("%s", ch);` -> format '%s' expects argument of type 'char *', but argument 2 has type 'char (*)[51]' [-Werror=format=]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem with the algorithm of the `do-while` loop.

The counter `i` increments short before the condition check.

If `'\0'` is found in the next array element (Note, that `i` is incremented) the loop breaks immediately and won´t be able to set `length` to `i` at the next iteration (because there is no next iteration).

Since `length` is not initialized, the program has [undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior).

Change:

```
do
{
   if (ch[i] == '\0')
   {
       length = i;
   }
   else
   {
       i++;
   }
}
while (ch[i] != '\0');
```

to

```
while (ch[i] != '\0') i++;

length = i;
```

or even simpler:

```
while (ch[i] != '\0') length++;
```

and omit the counter `i`, but you need to initialize `length` by `0` then.

---

Side Notes:

1. Change `scanf("%s", &ch);` to `scanf("%s", ch);`. - `ch` decays to a pointer to its first element.
2. Use a length modifier at `scanf()` -> `scanf("%50s", ch);` to ensure that no buffer overflow occurs when the user inputs a string longer than 50 characters.
3. Always check the return value of `scanf()` if an error occurred at consuming input.
4. Never ignore at the compiler warnings. For `scanf("%50s", ch);` the compiler should have raised a warning.

Comment: Thank you so much ! perfect answer now i understood the error ! i appreciate it friend.

Comment: @BacimOueslati I'm glad that I could help you. Also take a look at the side notes, I've added. They are important, too.

Comment: i did and they're very helpful. Thank you so much !

Comment: @BacimOueslati Found a way to make it even simpler. You can omit the counter `i` at all.

Comment: even simpler `for(length=0; ch[length]; length++);`